# Shiny: How to separate list of radio buttons with headers

Tags: r, shiny

Right now I've got something like this:

```
wellPanel(
            titlePanel(h3("Common Plots")),
            # Bar Plots
            radioButtons(
                ns("selected_graph"), 
                label = h4("Bar Plots"),
                choices = barChoices,
                selected = 'bar_1'
            ),

            # Scatter Plots
            radioButtons(
                ns("selected_graph"), 
                label = h4("Scatter Plots"),
                choices = scatterChoices
            ),

            # Other
            radioButtons(
                ns("selected_graph"), 
                label = h4("Other Plots"),
                choices = otherChoices
            )
        )
```

Which looks like:

[image: Picture w/ list of radio buttons separated by headers]

The point here is to have radio buttons separated nicely by headers (Bar Plot, Scatter Plot, etc.) but still update the same value—so that you can only select a *single* radio button, and everything is updated appropriately. I then return the value as a reactive:

```
# Return the choice user selects
sidePanel <- function(input, output, session) {
    selected_graph <- reactive({input$selected_graph})
    return(selected_graph)
}
```

What ends up happening is that only the radio buttons in the *first* group of radio buttons register. I can click between the choices in the first group and things update accordingly, but when I click between choices in either of the other two groups, nothing happens. How can I get these radio buttons to update the same value?

Comment: I don't know shiny modules (`ns`) but it seems that you use the same id for the three groups. You need different ids.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Using different IDs would defeat the purpose of my question. :l The point is that the user can select only *one* of the radio buttons; the only reason for having them in 3 separate groups is to be able to separate them w/ labels. Otherwise I want them to update the same value. Or are you saying that things just won't work in general w/ the same ID?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when I encountered a very similar problem. I also couldn't find a fancy solution so I wrote a function.

```
groupRadioButtons <- function(widget,
                              index,
                              groups,
                              type = c("default", "pretty", "awesome"),
                              style = "margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;") {
  stopifnot("shiny.tag" %in% class(widget))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(index))
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (length(style) != length(groups)) style <- rep(style, length(groups))
  is_awesome <- type %in% "awesome"
  is_pretty <- type %in% "pretty"

  for (i in seq_along(index)) {
    idx <- index[i]
    grp <- groups[i]
    sty <- style[i]
    fidx <- ifelse(is_awesome, 3, 2)
    
    if (is_pretty) {
      if (idx == 1) {
        widget$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$children <- grp
        widget$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$attribs$style <- sty
      } else {
        widget$children[[2]]$children[[2]][[idx - 1]][[2]]$children <- grp
        widget$children[[2]]$children[[2]][[idx - 1]][[2]]$attribs$style <- sty
      }
    } else {
      widget$children[[fidx]]$children[[1]][[idx]]$children <- append(
        widget$children[[fidx]]$children[[1]][[idx]]$children,
        tagList(div(grp, style = style[i])),
        after = 0
      )
    }
  }
  
  widget
}
```

The idea is to provide a radioButtons widget, an index vector (where should the headers be placed?), and a group vector (what should the header look like?). The function then iterates through indices and groups and places a styled header at the respective radio items. It works for `shiny::radioButtons()`, `shinyWidgets::awesomeRadio()`, and `shinyWidgets::prettyRadioButtons()`.

A small example Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

rb <- radioButtons(
  "radio1",
  "Default radio",
  choices = c(
    "a", "b", "c",
    "1", "2", "3"
  )
) %>%
  groupRadioButtons(
    index = c(1, 4),
    groups = list(
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Letters"), br()),
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Numbers"), br())
    )
  )

rb_pretty <- prettyRadioButtons(
  "radio2",
  "Pretty radio",
  choices = c(
    "a", "b", "c",
    "1", "2", "3"
  )
) %>%
  groupRadioButtons(
    index = c(1, 4),
    type = "pretty",
    groups = list(
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Letters"), br()),
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Numbers"), br())
    )
  )

rb_awesome <- awesomeRadio(
  "radio3",
  "Awesome radio",
  choices = c(
    "a", "b", "c",
    "1", "2", "3"
  )
) %>%
  groupRadioButtons(
    index = c(1, 4),
    type = "awesome",
    groups = list(
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Letters"), br()),
      tagList(hr(), tags$b("Numbers"), br())
    )
  )

ui <- fixedPage(
  fixedRow(
    column(1),
    column(2, rb),
    column(2, rb_pretty),
    column(2, rb_awesome),
    column(7)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 inputs with the same id, they will clash.

Using `selectInput` instead of `radioButtons` would be a good solution to your problem. `selectInput` supports groups out of the box.

Here is a reprex from `?selectInput` docs:

[image: group support in choices arg demo]

```r
# Demoing group support in the `choices` arg
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "state",
    label = "Choose a state:",
    choices = list(
      `East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
      `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
      `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")
    )
  ),
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$result <- renderText({
    paste("You chose", input$state)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```